# Passing variables between two WxPython windows

Tags: python, class, parameters, wxpython

So im writing a program and i need to get a list from the main GUI window to the pop up window that does an action with the selected options from the main window

the problem is i cant pass a variable when i call the class for the new window

When i create the instance i want to pass the list

```
act = Action(None, "Action")
```

but it only lets me pass the name of the window and if i try to create a new parameter i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Invent Manager.py", line 274, in auction
    act = Action(None, "Action", "item")
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Invent Manager.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.InitUI()    
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Invent Manager.py", line 357, in InitUI
    main = GUI()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

here is my init of my pop up window:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title, item_id):
        super(Action, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(200, 200))
        self.InitUI()    
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
```

someone please tell me how i can do this!

here is the main GUI's `__init__`:

```
class GUI(wx.Frame):
    #GUI
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self.inv = GetInvent()
        self.inv.Login()
        self.packages = self.inv.getinv()
        self.packages2 = self.inv.getSDB()
        self.id_list = self.inv.id_list

        self.show = 1

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(450, 400))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. replaced `__init__` signature to make arguments optional except parent, title:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Action, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(200, 200))
        self.InitUI()    
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
```

Comment: so now i can add new parameters or what?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, You can add new parameters (before `*args`).

Comment: so say i wanted to add an `item` parameter how would i call that?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, I don't understand what you mean.. Call it as `...(parent, title, item)`?

Comment: no i still get the same error when i create the instance like this `act = Action(None, "Action",item)`

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, `__init__` in your question is GUI's or Action's?

Comment: Its the Action pop up init

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, Could you show both (`GUI.__init__`, `Action.__init__`)?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, There are 3 parameter (excluding self) in `GUI.__init__`, but you don't pass any parameter.

Comment: Ohhhh that was an accident i wrote that line when i was trying stuff i thought the error was coming from when i call the action gui !!